# redis-server, node_modules, nodejs, npm

Tags: node.js, server, redis, visual-web-developer

I attempted to download and configure redis for windows in my project's node_modules but all the tutorials I searched up are old. The command in particular that I want access to is redis-server. How can I download redis 5.0 on windows without using a vm? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis does not run natively on windows. There are some older versions of Redis which are ported to windows, but they are no longer maintained. Best alternative would be to run your project in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Here are some options:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-windows

Comment: so if I run the project stored in my desktop of my windows computer, in ubuntu which is stored in my system 32, will it run through the ubuntu terminal, although I code it in my windows dir? Or is there a special dir for ubuntu on windows where I can store my project?

Comment: I guess the standard way of working would be to store your files on your windows file system. You can access the windows C:/ disk through /mnt/c/ in your ubuntu terminal. If you don't want to go through the hassle of opening a separate ubuntu terminal, VScode has some good integration with WSL system. Here is some documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Comment: on the ubuntu terminal on my windows machine, I cannot navigate as if it was a regular windows directory. How can I reach my windows directory or my file stored in my windows directory through ubuntu. Eg. cd c/user/.../desktop/... does not work, instead it's like root folder, home, then my username I setup for ubuntu, but I am not sure on how to access my window's file on this terminal.

Comment: In the linux terminal, try `cd /mnt`. You will then see your C:/ drive.

Comment: thank you for your help, I got it to work through ubuntu.